# Is there a way to access the last match information while iterating with `String#split`?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, iteration

I want to iterate over a string with a regex pattern. I need to iterate over the matches as well as **the non-matches in between them**, and access the match information while iteration.

If I do not need to access the non-matches, then I can do it with `String#scan`:

```
"some string".scan(/(some pattern)|(another pattern)/) do
  if $1 then ...
  elsif $2 then ...
  end
end
```

But I need to iterate over the non-matching parts as well, so I probably need to use `String#split`. But `String#split` does not take a block, and if I use `each` after it like:

```
"some string".split(/((some pattern)|(another pattern))/).each do
  ...
end
```

then, I cannot access the match information in the block. I want to do something like:

```
"some string".split(/((some pattern)|(another pattern))/) do
  if $2 then ...
  elsif $3 then ...
  else ... # access the non-matching part
  end
end
```

Is there a way to access the last match information while iterating with `String#split`?

I can brute force it by using `scan` and adding `|(.*?)` at the end of the regex:

```
"some string".scan(/(some pattern)|(another pattern)|(.*?)/) do
  if $1 then ...
  elsif $2 then ...
  elsif $3 then ...
  end
end
```

but using a non-greedy match is very inefficient, and I cannot use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only process the string one match at a time using `match` instead of all at once as with `scan`, you can inject data from `pre_match` in with your results:

```
def match_all(s, r)
  match = s.match(r)

  if match
    pre_captures = [match.pre_match] + match.captures.map{nil}
    captures = [nil] + match.captures
    [pre_captures, captures] + match_all(match.post_match, r)
  else
    [[s]]
  end
end
```

This code transforms the input string into tuples that represent `[unmatched data, first match group, second match group, etc...]` and then the data can be iterated as you like:

```
match_all("the match information in the block", /(at)|(in)/).each do |a, b, c|
  if a
    puts "(pre: #{a})"
  elsif b
    puts "(1st: #{b})"
  elsif c
    puts "(2nd: #{c})"
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
(pre: the m)
(1st: at)
(pre: ch )
(2nd: in)
(pre: form)
(1st: at)
(pre: ion )
(2nd: in)
(pre:  the block)
```

The same function can also be implemented iteratively like so:

```
def match_all_iter(s, r)
  s_mut = s
  all_captures = []

  loop do
    match = s_mut.match(r)

    break unless match

    pre_captures = [match.pre_match] + match.captures.map{nil}
    captures = [nil] + match.captures
    all_captures += [pre_captures, captures]

    s_mut = match.post_match
  end

  all_captures += [[s_mut]]
end
```

Comment: It works, the idea is good, but it is not preferable to use recursive call like this. Perhaps you can do a similar thing using iteration instead.

Comment: @sawa added iterative version

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an idea of iterating over the non-matching part and the matching part together per match cycle. This uses `scan` instead of `split`, and will fulfill the purpose.

```
s = "some string"
i = 0
s.scan(/(some pattern)|(another pattern)|\z/) do
  # Do something with the non-matching part
  ... s[i...$~.begin(0)] ... # This corresponds to the string in between
  i = $~.end(0)
  # Do something with the matching part
  if $1 then ...
  elsif $2 then ...
  end
end
```